# QT XCB plugin missing libxcb-icccm.so.4

Tags: qt, xcb

I have installed miniconda3 and I am trying to run QT designer.  I have a Linux machine in multi-user mode so I have to run QT using X11 utilizing the XCB plugin.  The error that I am receiving is:

```
Cannot load library /usr/local/bin/anaconda3/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (libxcb-icccm.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

I cannot find this libscb-icccm.so.4 file on my machine.  How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter QT plugin and `ldd libqxcb.so`, and find where path `libxcb-icccm.so.4` should setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyeyM.png)

```
sudo find / -name libxcb-icccm.so* (find libxcb-icccm.so*)<br>
sudo cp src_path/libxcb-icccm.so* dir_path<br>
```

Comment: I just had to keep installing libxcb packages to get it all working.  When ldd shows no broken links then it works